# Flutter Firebase Google Authentication: How to get a new JWT idToken once same expires

Tags: android, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

**Scenario:** I have an app(gcpapp) running on GCP that is secured with IAP and I am able to connect to an API inside gcpapp with following code.

```
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart' as sign_in;
....
final sign_in.GoogleSignInAccount _googleSignInAccount = 
                     await sign_in.GoogleSignIn().signInSilently();
final googleSignInAuthentication = await _googleSignInAccount.authentication;

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: await Firebase.initializeApp());
```

result of `print(_auth.currentUser);`:

`User(displayName: ******, email: *****@gmail.com, emailVerified: true, isAnonymous: false, metadata: UserMetadata(creationTime: 2021-05-27 12:08:06.692, lastSignInTime: 2021-05-28 08:40:47.806), phoneNumber: null, photoURL: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/**********, providerData, [UserInfo(displayName: *******, email: *****@gmail.com, phoneNumber: null, photoURL: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/*********************, providerId: google.com, uid: *****************)], refreshToken: , tenantId: null, uid: ********************)`

Below code works fine for 1 hour, when JWT is valid.

```
final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse("IAP protected URL.........."),
        body: null, //null FOR TESTING
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + googleSignInAuthentication.idToken
        }
      );
```

However, if I try the same code after JWT has expired, response.body is:
`OpenID Connect token expired: JWT has expired`

I have checked for a solution and it seems I need a `refreshToken` to get a new JWT, but as you can see in the User details from above, I am getting an empty string for the `refreshToken`. I am not able to figure out what do I need to do so that I can get a `refreshToken` in the original signIn() that can be used for requesting a new JWT

**UPDATE 2021.05.29**

Based on these two answers: [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62230577/9538337) & [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63967005/9538337) I tried the following code:

```
final UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: null, // googleSignInAuthentication.idToken
    ));
```

[using `idToken:googleSignInAuthentication.idToken` instead of `idToken: null` above returned error: `The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired`]

which returned a new value for `googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken` that I used in the below code as `refresh_token`:

```
final url = Uri.parse('https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=$WEB_API_KEY');

final response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    body: {
      'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
      'refresh_token': googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    },
);
```

which returns `INVALID_REFRESH_TOKEN` error.

If anyone who has faced similir issue in the past and has resolved it could shed some light on this, that will be a great help!!